# Filter phone numbers from open text field - Power BI, excel, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi

I have a text field in a table where I need to substitute phone numbers where applicable.

For example the text field could have:

```
Call me on 08588812885 immediately
Call me on 07525812845
I need assistance please contact me
Good service
```

Sometimes a phone number will be in the text but not always and the phone number entered will always be different.

Is there a measure to use to replace the phone numbers with no text.

Ideally the solution would be Power BI, but can also be done in the raw data using excel or VBA

Comment: Can you edit your sample data so it's more clear what text can be found in a cell? Also, can you cover more options of phone numbers? Also relevant: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: excel 2016 and sample data: Call me on 08588812885 immediately, Call me on 07525812845, I need assistance please contact me, Good service

Comment: So, do you need to replace the phone number with another one, keeping the rest of the text as it is?

Comment: If all numbers start with `0` and only a single (phone)number exist you could use `REPLACE()` (but making sure phonenumbers are 10 characters long). Otherwise you'd probably want to use regular expressions within VBA. Not sure about PowerBI.

Comment: I would want to take the phone number out or anonymise this. There could be other number values in the open text like years 2020.

Comment: @jvdv how would replace work if I don't know the starting he phone number? and what would i write in vba?

Comment: `REPLACE()` is only useful if phonenumbers **always** start with a zero **and** no other numbers start with zero **and** phonenumbers are always 10 digits long **and** there is only a single phonenumber in each cell. In vba, you'd need to research how to use regular expressions and come up with a pattern to match any type of valid phonenumber you are interested in.

Comment: @jdv I know replace and vba are options, I am asking here how to implement these on my test data

Comment: You can replace all numbers in your text by nothing. Remember, this will replace all numbers regardless its a phone number or not.

Comment: I ma looking to only replace the phone numbers in the text and not other numbers such as a year 2017 in the text

Comment: Then what is the number pattern to identify a phone number in a text? You need to provide the logic and some more possible sample text that covered all your scenario.

Comment: it is 11 digits as displayed in the sample data, all uk based so no country code prefix

Comment: anyone able to provide a solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression in VBA (excel) or Python (Power BI) is a straightforward solution.

I have never used PowerBI with Python before but manage to make following python script.
In PowerBI transformation steps I created a new column that would copy [message] columns and named it [noPhoneNumber], then next step ran this python script

```
import re

def removePhone(x):
    return re.sub('\d{10,11}', "**number removed**", x)

length = len(dataset["noPhoneNumber"])

for iRow in range(length):
    dataset["noPhoneNumber"][iRow] = removePhone(dataset["noPhoneNumber"][iRow])
```

so column "noPhoneNumber"

```
Call me on 08588812885 immediately
Call me on 07525812845
I need assistance please contact me
Good service
```

becomes

```
Call me on **number removed** immediately
Call me on **number removed**
I need assistance please contact me
Good service
```

In VBA Preferable create UDF (user defined function) and don't create a subroutine, that would be too error prone for this kind of problem.

[Added]
If you need to make a Excel based solution, you can create a UDF function like so:
(remember early binding to import of VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp in excel)

```
Function removePhoneNumber(text As String, Optional replacement As String = "**number removed**") As String
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "\d{10,11}"
    removePhoneNumber = regex.Replace(text, replacement)
End Function
```

...and then use excel function like so:

```
=removePhoneNumber(A2),
=removePhoneNumber(A3)
and so on...
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed comment, the only issue the client I am being asked to do this for will not be able to use Python and have asked for an excel based solution. I have intermediate VBA skills but this issue I am not sure where to begin, Would you mind drafting up code as you seem to be fluent with this and I will test it?

Comment: @RyanB: You should only copy the function (`removePhoneNumber`) in a standard module and add a reference to 'VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp' (Being in VBE: Tools -> References..., scroll down until find the reference in discussion, check it and press OK). I would adapt the function to also accept an `Optional` parameter (the number to replace the existing one)... `Function removePhoneNumber(text As Variant, Optional strReplace As String) As String` and adapt `regex.Replace(text, strReplace)` instead of `regex.Replace(text, "*number removed*")`.

Comment: @RyanB: It can be called from a cell like `=removePhoneNumber(A2, "12345678900")` or simple 'removePhoneNumber(A2)`, when the number will be just removed (not replaced).

Comment: Nice... Voted it up. It maybe would be good do adapt the function in the way I recommended to @RyanB. It would be able to **replace or remove** the phone number in discussion. This will also help him, who does not look very experienced in VBA... And maybe more votes up will come. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple VBA function alternative

```
Function removePhone(s As String) As String
Const DELIM As String = " "
Dim i As Long, tokens As Variant
tokens = Split(s, DELIM)
For i = LBound(tokens) To UBound(tokens)
    If IsNumeric(tokens(i)) Then
        tokens(i) = "*Removed*" ' << change to your needs
        Exit For                ' assuming a single phone number per string
    End If
Next
removePhone = Join(tokens, DELIM)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Power Query. Create a custom column with this below code. I have considered the column name is **Comments** but please adjust this with your column name.

```
if Text.Length(Text.Select([comments], {"0".."9"})) = 11
then 
    Text.Replace(
        [comments],
        Text.Select([comments], {"0".."9"}),
        ""
    )
else [comments]
```

Here is the output below. You can also replace phone numbers with other text like #### to make is anonymous.

[image]

**NOTE**

> This will only work if there are only 1 number in the string with length 11 (You can adjust the length in code as per requirement).

> This will **Not** work if there are more than one **Numbers** in the string.

> If there are 1 number in the string but length not equal 11, this will keep the whole string as original.